# deleting files from s3 bucket using simple db

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to delete the files on Amazon s3 bucket using simpledb. But for some reason it does not delete the file and says that it has deleted it.

I am using S3 classdeleteObject method to delete the file. 
Below is the sample code :

```
$bucketName = "bucket";
$s3 = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);
if ($s3->deleteObject($bucketName, $url))
{
    echo "deleted url";
}
else
{
    echo "cannot delete";
}
```

After execution the script echoes "deleted url" which should happen when deletion is successfully completed. But when I open the URL again, the file is still there and has not been deleted.

Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *unofficial* S3.php class. The GitHub repo with documentation is here: https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

This code is *not* provided by AWS, and should not be confused with either [AWS SDK for PHP 1.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/) or [AWS SDK for PHP 2.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are giving the right `file name for the object` in `parameter`. I guess, you are storing file in `Amazon S3` and you are keeping the `URL` of that file into `Amazon SimpleDB`. So you need to provide a valid `file name` in parameter instead of `URL`.